# error to send mail (gmail to gmail)

Tags: c#

I want to send mail  (gmail to gmail) this is the code with c#:
 I now it's easy and exist more tuto.
 I test all tuto to send mail but always the same problem

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
namespace VerificationBlockage
{
    class EnvoyerMail
    {


        public void sendEmail()
        {

            // Mail message construction
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("halloula.briki@gmail.com", "halloula.briki@mail.com");

            // content
            mm.Subject = "testing message";
            mm.Body = "hello... from .net c# mailmessage";
            mm.CC.Add("mejdi68@mail.com");
           // mm.CC.Add("copycc2@mail.com");
           // mm.Bcc.Add("copybcc@mail.com");

            // some attachments
            //mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("c:\\filename.txt"));

            // Sending message
            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            sc.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            // ...

            // our account credentials
            sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("halloula.briki@gmail.com", "&******&");
            sc.EnableSsl = true;

            // Catching result
            try
            {
                sc.Send(mm);
                MessageBox.Show("Message sent");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }



    }
}
```

I don't what's the problem. I change the port 25 , 587, 465.
the error is ***le serveur ne prend pas en charge les connexions sécurisées***

English Translation:

> the server does not support secure connections

Comment: Can you please translate your error message to English?

Comment: Error: le serveur SMTP requiest une connexion sécurisé ou le client n'était pas authentifié. la repense du serveur était: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Comment: the server does not support secure connections

Comment: or SMTP server requiest a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. rethinks the server was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Answer (score 1):

This suggests the server you are using does not support SSL connections.

Remove the line

```
sc.EnableSsl = true;
```

Or Change it to:

```
sc.EnableSsl = false;
```

However I am fairly sure Gmail does.  Try this:

```
public string SendGmailMessage(string toAddress, string fromAddress, string ccAddress, string subject, string body)
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    string msg = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        MailAddress emailFrom = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
        message.From = emailFrom;
        message.To.Add(toAddress);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccAddress))
    {
            message.CC.Add(ccAddress);
    }
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = body;
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;  //Add this line
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("GMAILUSERNAME", "GMAILPASSWORD");

        smtpClient.Send(message);
        msg = "Message Sent";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        msg = ex.Message;
    }
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: error: A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll

Comment: I am behind a firewall so cannot test this actual code until I get home in an hour.  Are you behind a firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that depends on the gmail service connected to that port (server side).
I've seen some examples using SSL connecting to port 465

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely an issue with your firewall. Have you checked it? On your cmd prompt check the following:

`Telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`

If you do not get a valid response back something is blocking that port.

Answer (score 0):

You canset Gmail to allow such activity (which is blocked for security reasons by default...) here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps . Good luck!